# Android Programming via USB Stick

Tags: android, eclipse, mobile, sdk, usb

I am programming android apps but am not very experienced with it mainly because of to less time for it.
I'm working at a place, where i often have a little free time for coding, but no admin Privileges on the PCs. So does someone maybe have experience with installing and running

- Anroid SDK (SDK Manager,APIs)
- Emulator
- Eclipse (and nessecary plugins for andoid programming)
- ADB

from an usb Stick i'd love to get tipps for that. Also i want to connect my Phone as a physical testing device. I used to test on that device earlier so developper options should be activated on this.

I hope, this is is no duplicate question, did not find s.th. via search. Sorry for the bad english, im not a native speaker.

Comment: This is probably better suited for android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @Chris: *[definitely not](http://android.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)*.